# Make my MySQL query less verbose

Tags: mysql

The following query was a real challenge for me to build for a Wordpress site using the wordpress wp_post table and the wp_postmeta table and the wp_user table. It works perfectly but it contains a lot of repeated statements. I am not sure how to simplify this (or if it can be). Any tips for simplifying and ridding the repetition would be appreciated.

The tables contain data like this:

```
wp_posts
 ID | post_author | post_parent | post_type    | post_title | post_date
2258  163           0             fep_message    a
2262  1             2258          fep_message    re:a
2264  163           2258          fep_message    re:a
1698  1             0             fep_message    b
1692  1             0             fep_message    c

wp_postmeta
meta_id | post_id | meta_key          | meta_value
14696     2258      _fep_participants   1
14697     2258      _fep_participants   163
9819      1698      _fep_participants   163
9820      1698      _fep_participants   1
9759      1692      _fep_participants   163
9760      1692      _fep_participants   1
9815      1692      _fep_delete_by_1    1499496054
13751     1698      _fep_delete_by_163  1501044119

wp_user
ID   | user_login 
1      myname
163    theirname
```

This is the query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
SELECT p.id, p.post_date, p.post_title, uf.user_login AS from_login, ut.user_login AS to_login 
FROM wp_posts AS p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_to
    ON  (p.id = pm_to.post_id 
    AND pm_to.meta_key = '_fep_participants' 
    AND p.post_parent = 0 
    AND pm_to.meta_value <> p.post_author)
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_delete
    ON (p.id = pm_delete.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS uf ON uf.ID = p.post_author 
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS ut ON ut.ID = pm_to.meta_value    
WHERE (p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND uf.user_login = 'myname'
OR p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND ut.user_login = 'myname')
AND p.post_date >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00'  
AND p.post_date <= '2017-08-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY p.post_date
) a

UNION

SELECT b.*
FROM (
SELECT p.id, p.post_date, p.post_title, uf.user_login AS from_login, ut.user_login AS to_login 
FROM wp_posts AS p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_to
    ON (p.post_parent = pm_to.post_id 
    AND p.post_parent <> 0 
    AND pm_to.meta_key = '_fep_participants' 
    AND pm_to.meta_value <> p.post_author) 
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_delete
    ON (p.id = pm_delete.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS uf ON uf.ID = p.post_author 
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS ut ON ut.ID = pm_to.meta_value    
WHERE (p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND uf.user_login = 'myname'
OR p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND ut.user_login = 'myname')
AND p.post_date >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00'  
AND p.post_date <= '2017-08-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY p.post_date
) b
```

The result it produces is:

```
id     |post_date              |post_title     |from_login     |to_login    
1692    2017-07-07 11:45:03     c               myname          theirname   
1698    2017-07-08 16:28:18     b               myname          theirname   
2258    2017-08-11 23:15:10     a               theirname       myname  
2262    2017-08-12 16:48:05     re:a            myname          theirname
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I didn't check if your 2 parts are otherwise equal (which is something you could easily add to the question, to prevent that everyone would have to check for it again), but if the code differs only in the `on`-condition, you can simply combine both cases with an `or`, e.g. `JOIN wp_postmeta pm_to ON  (p.id = pm_to.post_id AND p.post_parent = 0 ... ) or (p.post_parent = pm_to.post_id AND p.post_parent <> 0 ...)`. If there are other differences, you can add the condition there in a similar way, although at some point, it will probably get less readably than splitting it in unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Solaflare.  That did it.  This is my simplification:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_date, p.post_title, uf.user_login AS from_login, ut.user_login AS to_login 
FROM wp_posts AS p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_to
    ON  ((p.id = pm_to.post_id 
    AND p.post_parent = 0) OR (p.post_parent = pm_to.post_id 
    AND p.post_parent <> 0)) 
    AND pm_to.meta_key = '_fep_participants' 
    AND pm_to.meta_value <> p.post_author)
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_delete
    ON (p.id = pm_delete.post_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS uf ON uf.ID = p.post_author 
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS ut ON ut.ID = pm_to.meta_value    
WHERE (p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND uf.user_login = 'myname'
OR p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND pm_delete.meta_value <> '_fep_delete_by_1' AND ut.user_login = 'myname')
AND p.post_date >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00'  
AND p.post_date <= '2017-08-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY p.post_date
```